# Using EitherT to evaluate the results of operations using a shared error type inheritance?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, for-comprehension

I have an error type hierarchy for peeling bananas:

```
sealed trait PeelBananaError
object PeelBananaError {
  case object TooRipe extends PeelBananaError
  case object NotRipeEnough extends PeelBananaError
}
```

And I have some results in `EitherT` that we know can only fail in one of the two ways:

```
val peelBrownBananaResult: EitherT[Future, TooRipe, String] = ...
val peelGreenBananaResult: EitherT[Future, NotRipeEnough, String] = ...
```

Now I need to gather the `String` results from the right and combine them for a final result:

```
val combinedResult: EitherT[Future, PeelBananaError, String] = for {
  first <- peelBrownBananaResult
  second <- peelGreenBananaResult
} yield (first + second)
```

But trying this out gives me a compile error:

```
cmd15.sc:2: inferred type arguments [PeelBananaError.NotRipeEnough.type,String] do not conform to method flatMap's type parameter bounds [AA >: PeelBananaError.TooRipe.type,D]
  first <- peelBrownBananaResult
           ^
cmd15.sc:2: type mismatch;
 found   : String => cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,PeelBananaError.NotRipeEnough.type,String]
 required: String => cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,AA,D]
  first <- peelBrownBananaResult
        ^
Compilation Failed
```

It seems the compiler is unable to infer that the `Left` types share a common inheritance in `PeelBananaError` so the for comprension does not compile. Is there any workaround here? Some hint I can give to the compiler so I can run this for comprehension?

I have tried the following, but using `.asInstanceOf` seems so hacky and the resulting code looks very ugly, is this really the only solution?

```
val combinedResult: EitherT[Future, PeelBananaError, String] = for {
  first <- peelBrownBananaResult.asInstanceOf[EitherT[Future,PeelBananaError,String]]
  second <- peelGreenBananaResult.asInstanceOf[EitherT[Future,PeelBananaError,String]]
} yield (first + second)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EitherT` monad transformer is not covariant in `A` or `B` type parameters

```
case class EitherT[F[_], A, B]
```

unlike `Either` which is covariant in `A` and `B`

```
sealed abstract class Either[+A, +B]
```

which is why `Either` type-checks to a supertype

```
Either.left(TooRipe): Either[PeelBananaError, String] // ok
```

but `EitherT` does not

```
EitherT.left(Future(TooRipe)): EitherT[Future, PeelBananaError, String] // error
```

However we can safely [widen](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/09/29/monad-transformer-variance.html) monad transformers

```
for {
  first <- peelBrownBananaResult.leftWiden[PeelBananaError]
  second <- peelGreenBananaResult.leftWiden[PeelBananaError]
} yield (first + second)
// : EitherT[Future, PeelBananaError, String] = ...
```

unlike unsafe widening with `asInstanceOf`

```
type T = Either[TooRipe.type, String]
val a = Either.left[PeelBananaError, String](new PeelBananaError {})
val b: Either[TooRipe.type, String] = a.asInstanceOf[T] // run-time error
val c: Either[TooRipe.type, String] = a.widen[T]        // compile-time error
```